# Dynamic naming key Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql, mongoengine

How do I create a dynamic mongoengine key? That way I will be able to query by the name for example.
Here is example of what I'm aiming to:

```
{
  "joe": {
   "score": 20
  },
  "bob": {
   "score": 30
  }
...
}
```

So the model should be something like that:

```
class user{name}(EmbeddedDocument):
    score = IntField()

class users(Document):
    user(EmbeddedDocumentField)
    score = IntField()
```

Is it possible to achieve it with mongoengine?

Answer (score 1):

The [DictField](https://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.DictField) might help you to get there, see below

```
from mongoengine import *
connect()


class UserScore(EmbeddedDocument):
    score = IntField()
    
class Simple(Document):
    mapping = DictField(field=EmbeddedDocumentField(UserScore))

e = Simple()
e.mapping["John"] = UserScore(score=5)
e.mapping["Bob"] = UserScore(score=10)
e.save()

# print the raw objects as stored in mongo
print(list(Simple.objects.as_pymongo()) # [{'_id': ObjectId('603cc7bca206e448e82c7437'), 'mapping': {'John': {'score': 5}, 'Bob': {'score': 10}}}]
```